# An 80s or early 90s (1990) animated sci-fi series that took place in space on a space ship

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, spaceship, space

The cartoon came in either the 80s or early 90s (probably 1990). The cartoon took place in space on a spaceship. The crew of the spaceship was human. The leader was a man and there was one female member of the crew who was either a brunette or a redhead. There was an episode where a villain made his crab-like creatures invade the crew's spaceship.

Comment: If it was live action I'd suggest the 90's Lost In Space movie.

Comment: see if this rings any bells: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starzinger Also if it is something from here: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceOpera

Comment: Remember any other details about the setting or plot? Animation style? What country did you watch it in?

Comment: How that spaceship looks like?

Comment: Maybe *Once Upon a Time... Space* aka *Il était une fois… l'Espace* aka *Galaxy Patrol PJ*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time..._Space

Comment: It's a bit late (late 90's IIRC) but Starship Troopers has an animated version, with Johnny Rico in charge and Dizzy Flores and/or Carmen Ibanez as 2IC I think.

Comment: Could be Robotech - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088595/

Comment: This is a long shot, but [Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0217941/) fits most of the criteria. Not sure if there was an episode with crab-like creatures invading the ship, though.